# Formula for finding the nth number in this sequence: $[0, 1, 3, 11, 50, 274...]$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, stirling-numbers

The sequence here is what I have discovered to be this: https://oeis.org/A000254, which references Stirling numbers of the First Kind. The formulas provided in that link are very ambiguous with their notation, and I have no idea what to take from them. Attempting to come up with a formula that will give me the nth number in the sequence, I've had to delve into research of Stirling numbers of the first kind and its definitions, which have proved largely ineffective in helping me derive this formula. I'm sure a formula for this already exists and is on the internet (or in someone's memory), I just haven't found it, and if anyone could provide this formula, or lead me toward deriving this formula, that would be fantastic. Thanks!

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Yes there are a lot of formulas. But there is one in particular near the top of the page. I'm confused because they write the formulas limited to everyday keyboard characters, instead of normal mathematical notation, which is understandable, don't get me wrong. I just can't interpret it. And where did this "$a$" come from?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Oh...

Comment: @WillOrrick I will definitely keep that in mind. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you provide has the following formula:
$$a(n)=n!\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n-k}$$
where $a(n)$ is the $n$th number in the series and $n\ge 1$.  Thus,

$a(0)=0$
$a(1)=1!\cdot\frac{1}{1-0}=1$
$a(2)=2!\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2-0}+\frac{1}{2-1}\right)=3$
$a(3)=3!\cdot\left(\frac{1}{3-0}+\frac{1}{3-1}+\frac{1}{3-2}\right)=11$
and so on.

---

There are a lot of other formulas on the link you provide, for example, $a(n)=a(n−1)\cdot(2n−1)−a(n−2)\cdot(n−1)^2$, if $n>1$.

$a(0)=0$
$a(1)=1$
$a(2)=a(2-1)\cdot(2\cdot 2-1)-a(2-2)\cdot(2-1)^2=a(1)\cdot 3-a(0)\cdot 1=1\cdot 3-0\cdot 1=3$
$a(3)=a(3-1)\cdot(2\cdot 3-1)-a(3-2)\cdot(3-1)^2=a(2)\cdot 5-a(1)\cdot 4=3\cdot 5-1\cdot 4=11$
and so on.

Another formula is $a(n+1)=(n+1)*a(n)+n!$, where $n\ge 0$

$a(0)=0$
$a(1)=1\cdot a(0)+0!=1\cdot 0+1=1$
$a(2)=2\cdot a(1)+1!=2\cdot 1+1=3$
$a(3)=3\cdot a(2)+2!=3\cdot 3+2\cdot 1=11$
and so on.

Comment: With this said, there's still the problem of deriving the formula I need.

Comment: I'm trying to derive a formula that will give me the nth term in the sequence. I referenced that page about this very sequence, as I was unsure whether it had already defined such a formula there or not, due to the confusion which was cleared up here. However, it seems it isn't defined there, so I still need to derive it. I apologize that the issue here is somewhat irrelevent to the question, I was just unsure.

Comment: Those formulas DO define $a_n$, but they have that $a_{n+1}$ that I don't want. I'm trying to derive/find a formula that will give me the nth term in the sequence without knowledge of any other terms in the sequence that could be substituted into the formula, as with those formulas, if that makes any sense. Is such a formula impossible?

Comment: How about $a(n)=n!\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n-k}$, where $n\ge 1$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I need! :)

Comment: Quite a strange way to write $n!H_n$, or 
$$n!\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$$